# How to add a button inside CListctrl in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc, clistctrl

I faced a big problem. My client requests a button inside each CListctrl item.

There is an example image below.

[image]

I searched Google for days on this but couldn't find any helpful information.

The information I searched for was all examples of the report method.
I need an implementation for View mode like the image above.

Could you please give me some example code or advice for reference?

Comment: CListCtrl is based on the standard Listview control, and that one is a very static control. You can typically only do with it what it is designed for. I can't remember having seen a button next to the item text. Tell your client it can't be done. Request time and expense to implement a control from scratch that allows the required features.

Comment: [List view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-control-reference) controls do not support hosting child controls. There's limited support for emulating child controls through [item state images](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/list-view-controls-overview#list-view-image-lists) (that's how check boxes are implemented). Item state images are always displayed to the left, and there can be at most one per item. They also depend on the view mode. I can't tell which view mode you are using from the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, look at it as an opportunity, NOT a problem :)

You can use `custom draw` to draw those buttons, then in your click handler see if the click was over one of those buttons.

Alternatively, you can create ONE single button and hide/move/show it as needed (in response to mouse move, for example).